error while starting the mariadb
Apr 15 15:21:23 ceph3 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 15 15:21:23 ceph3 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 15 15:21:23 ceph3 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.39 database server.
Apr 15 16:48:01 ceph3 systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.39 database server...
Apr 15 16:48:01 ceph3 mysqld[47049]: 2024-04-15 16:48:01 0 [Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 32768 (request: 36143)
Apr 15 16:48:01 ceph3 mysqld[47049]: 2024-04-15 16:48:01 0 [ERROR] Unknown collation: 'utf9_general_ci'
Apr 15 16:48:01 ceph3 mysqld[47049]: 2024-04-15 16:48:01 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Apr 15 16:48:01 ceph3 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 15 16:48:01 ceph3 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 15 16:48:01 ceph3 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.39 database server.


It looks like there is a typo in your collation settings - utf9_general_ci should almost certainly be utf8_general_ci (perhaps in the my.cnf file?)

how to remove utf8_general_ci

I don't know about MariaDB, but MySQL sources a lot of files, it's kind of a mess. Assuming MariaDB would source the same, which I honestly don't know, start with /etc/mysql/my.cnf and see if the typo is there. Otherwise refer to the files included from my.cnf itself, and then to table 6.2 here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html . Good luck...

As there is no utf9 you could probably just do sudo grep -R utf9 /etc and see what turns up.
